# Is 'working' a gerund in the following sentences?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech

Is 'working' a gerund in the following sentences?

> My mobile was not working
>
> He is working hard to pass the examination

Comment: Neither. The one in *He is working ...* is a verb; the one in *My mobile wasn't working* can be think of as a verb (it's similar to *It works*) or an adjective (It's working, so we can use it.) A gerund is the *-ing* form of a verb that functions as a noun. One good test to check if it's a gerund is to add a possessive adjective (*my*, *your*, *our*, *their*, etc.) in front of it. For example, *His running is strong* makes sense, so this *running* is a gerund. *\*He is my working hard to pass the examination* doesn't make sense (so, not a gerund).

Comment: First of all in sentence 1 you have Past continuous (was not working) and in 2 Present continuous. Whether "working" is a gerund or a participle is debatable. The traditional view of grammars is participle.

Answer (score 2):

When the verb has **the force of a noun** it is called ***gerund.***

In both of the sentences 'working' is used as a verb (in continuous tense).

Consider:

1. a. Working makes me tired. - Gerund

   b. He is working in the field. - verb
2. a. Working hard for the examination fetched him good grades.  - Gerund

   b. He is working hard for the examination. - verb

In the above sentences (a) 'working' has the force of a noun and it functions as a noun, so it is gerund. While in the sentences (b) 'working' is used as a verb.

Answer (score 0):

"was not working" is past tense continuous/progressive form. It consists of a form of to be and a verb form with the ending -ing. Today grammars say it is a present participle, but if you said it is a gerund (without preposition) it would be just as well.

You can say "I'm working" is "am + present participle" or
it is "am + (in the act of) working" or "am (at/on) working". Then it would be a gerund.

Sometimes I write: to be + gp (gerund or participle, whatever you like).

Answer (score 0):

*-ing* words are used to form **progressive or continuous constructions** if paired with a form of *to be*:

> was walking, am moving, were going, had been flying

Adverbs can come between *to be* and the -ing word, like *not*, *maybe*, *now*, etc.

Does this mean the *-ing* word is technically a gerund?  After all, you can replace the *walking* in *I was walking*, for example, with any noun, e.g. *I am a cat*.

However, *to be* is in a category of verbs called *linking* or *copular* verbs.  This means the X in *I am X* (or any other form of *to be*) can not only be a noun but also a modifier.  For example, you can say *I am hot*.

When a verb has the "force" of an modifier, it's a participle.  Then the argument could be made that the *-ing* word is modifying a verb so it's an adverb.

So it's not a simple question to say what part of speech the *walking* is in *I am walking*.  The model of considering *am walking* as a two-word verb is useful, but not sure how technically valid it really is from a hardcore analyticaL standpoint.  There's probably a couple pages deep in the CGEL that explain this.  If I remember and ever dig it up I'll update.